# Why am I getting a Mixin undefined error when compiling my LESS code?

Tags: css, less

I am new to LESS and am trying to create a complex structure to my LESS files so I can separate the front end framework files from my platform files from my client specific changes.... So to that end I have a structure using @import "filename.less"; like this (all separated into sub folders....)

```
master.less > platform.less > bootstrap.less > variables.less
                                             > mixins.less
                                             > ............etc

                            > font-awesome.less > ........etc

                            > bootstrap-ui.less > ........etc

                            > platform-variables.less
                            > platform-mixins.less
                              ......... etc

            > site.less > site-variables.less
                          ...............etc..
                          random-page.less
```

OK so master.less has a import to platform.less and site.less etc....

My question how come I am able to use the mixins defined in mixins.less file.... in random-page.less but not able to use the mixins defined in my custom mixin file in random-page.less (platform-mixins.less) that is called from the platform.less file I'm very confused....   please advise.

The error that I receive is:

```
>> NameError: .no-padding is undefined in css/site/random-page.less on line 75, column 3:
>> 74   .footer-sidebar {
>> 75           .no-padding;
>> 76   }
```

Which is true because it does not exist in this file?

However the bootstrap standard mixin works as expected despite the  clear fix mixin/class not existing in this file...

```
.footer-sidebar {
    .clearfix;
}
```

Comment: To say for sure we need to see how exactly this `.no-padding` is defined (For example is this really a mixin defined in the global scope and not something buried deep deep under other selector(s)?).

Comment: Sure my mixin is super simple:
    .no-padding() { padding:0; }
Just to be certain I checked the compiled code which is as expected:
    .no-padding { padding:0; }

Comment: So I can't see any reason why it coould be not visible. I'm afraid it's impossible to suggest anything w/o seeing the whole project. (As you say above Bootstrap mixins defined and used same way work just fine so it must be something very simple - for example don't you try to compile `site.less` separately from `master.less`? That way it won't work of course (countrary `platform.less` can be compiled alone since it includes all used components)). How do you compile all that, btw.?

Comment: Thanks for your input... Yes, all files get compiled into one CSS file... not separate files... I will investigate further in the morning and thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your help the issue is now resolved. It was not a result of the LESS structure shown above this worked fine. But as part of the build i was also generating further CSS files that also had a dependency on site.less file but didn't include the platform.less file DOE. Hence in this context the mixin was not found.

Answer (score 0):

To understand your structure, I created five files as follow:

1. master.less:

   ```
   .master {master:1;}
   @import "site";
   @import "platform";
   ```
2. platform.less

   ```
   .platform {platform:1;}
   @import "platform-mixins.less";
   ```
3. platform-mixins.less

   ```
   .platform-mixins {platform-mixins:1;}
   .platform-mixin() {color: red;}
   ```
4. random-page.less

   ```
   .random-page {
       .platform-mixin()
   }
   ```
5. site.less

   ```
   .site {site:1;}
   @import "random-page";
   ```

After that I run `lessc master.less` which outputs the following CSS code:

```
.master {
  master: 1;
}
.site {
  site: 1;
}
.random-page {
  color: red;
}
.platform {
  platform: 1;
}
.platform-mixins {
  platform-mixins: 1;
}
```

As expected, the .platform-mixin() from platform-mixins.less can be called without errors in random-page.less. So make sure that your mixin exists and that you really import the files you mention.